# Table/View 'ACCOUNTS' already exists in Schema 'APP'

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I'm not an experienced database developer.
Running a JDBC program with org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver. When I try to create an ACCOUNTS table, I use the following code:

```
  final String DRIVER =
     "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
  final String CONNECTION =
     "jdbc:derby:AccountDatabase;create=true";


  try {
     Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
  } catch ( ... etc.
  }


  try (Connection connection =
          DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION);

       Statement statement =
          connection.createStatement()) {

    statement.executeUpdate(
      "create table ACCOUNTS                       "
      + "  (NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "
      + "   ADDRESS VARCHAR(32),                   "
      + "   BALANCE FLOAT)                         ");
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Table/View 'ACCOUNTS' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
```

Then, when I try to update or query the ACCOUNTS table with the following code:

```
  final String DRIVER =
     "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
  final String CONNECTION =
     "jdbc:derby:AccountDatabase";


  try {
     Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
  } catch ( .. etc.
  }


  try (Connection connection =
     DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION);

     Statement statement =
        connection.createStatement();

     ResultSet resultset =
        statement.executeQuery(
                         "select * from ACCOUNTS")) {
```

I get the following error messages:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'AccountDatabase' not found.
```

Also, when I check for the existence of any tables with the following code, I get no tables at all:

```
        DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, null,
                new String[] { "TABLE" });
        System.out.println("List of tables: ");
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println("   " + res.getString("TABLE_CAT") + ", "
                    + res.getString("TABLE_SCHEM") + ", "
                    + res.getString("TABLE_NAME") + ", "
                    + res.getString("TABLE_TYPE") + ", "
                    + res.getString("REMARKS"));
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post: a) How you connect to the database b) What query / code you execute c) What error you get? That would help to answer your question.

Comment: When I try to create a table with this code...